# How to develop a weather application on android Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, weather

I would like to make an Android application using Google Map.

Can I show weather report on that map? If it's possible, which services has needed to get the weather report on map?

```
mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.myMapView);
mapView.setSatellite(true);
```

How to show the weather report on map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would want to look into [overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html). These allow you to position any information over your map and unlock a lot of powerful features for your users. I cant give a specific example since I don't know what data source you are getting weather information from. However I would suggest using the map center as your lat/lng and using a weather API to find the current conditions. Then overlay that on the map.

Comment: can i find weather API for android development.if it is please could you send link?

Comment: Well I would consider using a weather API from the web. It depends on the countries you want to support. Try a look at Wundergrounds API. http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML